# How to fix colReorder error - getAttribute is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a problem with jQuery DataTable СolReorder extension. In console I got error then I dragging a header:

> Uncaught TypeError: b.getAttribute is not a function

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#excel').DataTable( {
    stateSave: true,
    colReorder: {
        reorderCallback: function () {
            console.log( 'callback' );
        }
    }
} );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.2.0/css/colreorder.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="excel" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Haroldas</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>address</td>
            <td>eee</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>r</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>999</td>
            <td>rrr</td>
            <td>tttt</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>r</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ted</td>
            <td>333</td>
            <td>kkk</td>
            <td>null</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>r</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: copied code from jsfiddle into the question itself

Comment: Check console [here](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/examples/initialisation/simple.html). Same Issue.

Comment: yes problem same, but dragging not exactly too.

Comment: Harold dragging process here is bit complicated.because you cannot just drag n drop.Its like carrying column from one place to another .You have to do it smoothly then it will work.you can check example on datatable website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

There has been an issue [#623](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/623) with DataTables 1.10.8 causing the following error in the console: *TypeError: row.getAttribute is not a function at jquery.dataTables.js*.

> **SOLUTION**

Use DataTables 1.10.9 instead of 1.10.8.

> **DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#excel').DataTable( {
    stateSave: true,
    colReorder: {
        reorderCallback: function () {
            console.log( 'callback' );
        }
    }
} );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.2.0/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.2.0/css/colreorder.dataTables.min.css">

<table id="excel" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>number</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Haroldas</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>address</td>
            <td>eee</td>
            <td>f</td>
            <td>r</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tom</td>
            <td>999</td>
            <td>rrr</td>
            <td>tttt</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>r</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ted</td>
            <td>333</td>
            <td>kkk</td>
            <td>null</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>r</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```